# Is it required to specify the value type in a CAML query?

Tags: caml-query

I was wondering if CAML query Value Types are strongly typed or not. It would save me some time if I didn't have to specify "text" or "date" every time I made a query.

Here is the code I am using, its part of a helper method that allows me to grab an item based on a certain field and that field's value.

```
String camlQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='" + internalFieldName + "' /><Value Type='" + fieldType + "'>" + fieldValue + "</Value></Eq></Where>
```

I would like to get rid of the  if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily do but it is highly recomanded to do so when you know them (particularly for Lookup, User, Data) while filtering. Pasted more examples below for your reference.

```
<View>
   <ViewFields>
      <ProjectProperty Name="Title"      Nullable="TRUE" />
      <ProjectProperty Name="Url"        Nullable="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl"     Nullable="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef Name="PublishingContact" Nullable="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef Name="Title"                             />
      <FieldRef Name="FileRef"                           />
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"                          />
      <FieldRef Name="ID"                                />
      <FieldRef Name="Modified"                          />
      <FieldRef Name="Created"                           />
      <FieldRef Name="PublishingRollupImage"             />
      <FieldRef Name="Author"                            />
      <FieldRef Name="Editor"                            />
   </ViewFields>
   <Query>
      <Where>
         <And>
            <Or>
               <BeginsWith>
                  <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
                  <Value Type="Text">0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39001bb192640f8748d78db60217bd43598900f8c9db8d7f634c95bfd7ee95032f71c2</Value>
               </BeginsWith>
               <BeginsWith>
                  <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
                  <Value Type="Text">0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39001bb192640f8748d78db60217bd435989004896ce0317db45a9ae9e840754b48672</Value>
               </BeginsWith>
            </Or>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" />
               <Value Type="ModStat">Approved</Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
      </Where>
      <OrderBy>
         <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE" />
      </OrderBy>
   </Query>
   <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
</View>
```